# Discrepancy Between MATLAB and Python

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, physics, chemistry

I have a MATLAB script for calculating the entropy of a molecule according to its vibrational frequencies, and which I know to be correct by comparing it with experimental results. The MATLAB script is as follows:

```matlab
h=6.626*10^-34;
k=1.380*10^-23;
N=6.022*10^23;
n=N/1000;
R=N*k;
P0=101325; % Abhijit's operating pressure
m=16.042*1.67*10^-27;
T=975+273.15; % Abhijit's operating temperature
B=1/(k*T);
c=3*10^8;

v1=[3015,3006,2946,2894,1460,1455,1368,1241,1232,1000,945,652,252,223,183];
f1=v1*c*100;

s4ppafin=N*sum(((h*f1)/(T*(exp((B*h*f1)-1))))-(k*log(1-exp(-h*B*f1))))
```

This MATLAB code produces an output of 100.8006. My attempt to reproduce this code in Python is as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
# Do harmonic oscillator entropy approx. for the 4thppaFin system
c=3*10**8 # Approx. speed of light, m/s
h=6.626*10**-34 # Planck's constant, J/s
k=1.38*10**-23  # Boltzmann's constant, J/K
N=6.022*10**23  # Avogardo's number, particles/mole
R=N*k           # Ideal Gas Constant, J/(mol*k)
T=975+273.15    # Refernce temperature, Abhijit's operating condition
B=1/(k*T)       # Thermodynamic Beta

v=np.array([3015.0,3006,2946,2894,1460,1455,1368,1241,1232,1000,945,652,252,223,183],dtype=float)
f=np.array([c*100*i for i in v],dtype=float)
print(f)

q=[0]*len(f) # Part. func. init. for HO approx.
# q=np.array(q)

for i in range (len(f)):
  q[i]=((h*f[i])/(T*(np.exp((B*h*f[i])-1))))-(k*np.log(1-np.exp(-h*B*f[i])));

print(q)

S=N*sum(q)
print(S)
```

Here, the output is 145.25.

What is the cause for the Python script to produce a different number?

Comment: Yo I should not write `6.022*10^23` but rather `6.022e23`. This is true for both MATLAB and Python. In Python, since you’re using NumPy, you have access to the same vectorized computations as in MATLAB.  There is no need for explicit loops. You can write `f1=v1*c*100` in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your MATLAB script, in the last line:

```matlab
s4ppafin=N*sum(((h*f1)/(T*(exp((B*h*f1)-1))))-(k*log(1-exp(-h*B*f1))))
```

has a matrix division (`/`). I simplify your code for clarity:

```matlab
m1 = h*f1;
m2 = T*(exp((B*h*f1)-1));
m3 = k*log(1-exp(-h*B*f1));
s4ppafin = N * sum(m1/m2 - m3)
```

We see `m1/m2`. Both are 1x15 vectors. The division of the two vectors here is the least squares solution to an overdetermined system of equations:

```matlab
x * m2 = m1   =>   x = m1 / m2
```

Because `x` is scalar, this is actually easy to find:

```matlab
x = sum(m1 .* m2) ./ sum(m2 .^ 2)
```

You can compute this in Python in the same way. Note that MATLAB's `./` (element-wise division) is `/` in Python, MATLAB's `.*` is `*` in Python, and MATLAB's `*` is `@` in Python.

So in Python you can write:

```py
import numpy as np

# Do harmonic oscillator entropy approx. for the 4thppaFin system
c = 3e8 # Approx. speed of light, m/s
h = 6.626e-34     # Planck's constant, J/s
k = 1.38e-23      # Boltzmann's constant, J/K
N = 6.022e23      # Avogardo's number, particles/mole
R = N*k           # Ideal Gas Constant, J/(mol*k)
T = 975+273.15    # Refernce temperature, Abhijit's operating condition
B = 1/(k*T)       # Thermodynamic Beta

v1 = np.array([3015.0,3006,2946,2894,1460,1455,1368,1241,1232,1000,945,652,252,223,183])
f1 = v1*c*100

m1 = h*f1
m2 = T*(np.exp((B*h*f1)-1))
m3 = k*np.log(1-np.exp(-h*B*f1))
x = np.sum(m1 * m2) / sum(m2**2)
s4ppafin = N * np.sum(x - m3)
print(s4ppafin)
```

This produces the same output as your MATLAB code (100.8006).

Now, whether you intended to include this least squares solution in your original MATLAB code or not I cannot say, it seems to me that you didn't realize what `/` does in MATLAB with matrix inputs (because otherwise you would not have translated it this way in Python). Using `./` in MATLAB instead will produce the same result as your Python code (145.2506):

```matlab
s4ppafin = N * sum(m1./m2 - m3)
%                    ^^
```

Comment: Thank you Cris! I did imagine that the way MATLAB treats vectors was ultimately the root of the problem, but myself and another student were unable to see at a glance what the issue was. This was very helpful :)